# poner musica de fondo a mi web pero que sea continuo

Tags: php

en mi web le puse este codigo para tener musica de fondo

```html
<EMBED SRC="Music.mp3" AUTOSTART="true" HIDDEN="true" LOOP="true">
```

y funciona bien
mi consulta seria si se puede hacer continuo ???? por que actualmente si estoy en `index.php` y cambio a `descarga.php` (o a cualquier otro php) la musica se reinicia desde 0 y quisiera que sea continuo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la etiqueta `audio`. Este fragmento de código en el que utilizo la etiqueta `audio` funciona. La música sigue sonando de continuo cuando navego entre páginas.
He probado en las últimas versiones de los navegadores Chrome y Firefox. En ambos hay que configurar el navegador para que permita autoplay. De lo contrario no funcionará.

```
<audio width="320" height="176" controls autoplay loop>
<source src="Music.mp3"  type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: lo probe pero igual sigue reiniciandose al cambiar de php , ademas quisiera un sonido de fondo , no un reproductor